# AngularJS - What do I need to do manually when I use ngModelOptions allowInvalid = true?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and I'm now working on a pretty complex form that it looks like I could benefit by using the ngModelOptions `{ allowInvalid: true }` option.

I figure there is a good reason why AngularJS's default behavior is to blow away the model value if the invalid view value is invalid. My first guess is to ensure the invalid value is not passed to the server when the user submits the data.

So I guess my questions are

- What Angular features will I lose when using this option?
- I assume I need to manually check the validity of these values each time the user attempts to submit the data. Are there any Angular convenience methods I should consider using to check this data and display error messages?
- Is there anything else I'm missing that I need to think about when using this option?

Answer (score 2):

You do not lose any angular features other than of course it preventing invalid values being set on the model.

The model control is still marked as invalid, its just that instead of having the value set to undefined it will allow the invalid value to be set on the model.

One thing to watch for when using this flag is anything that is watching the model value. Since typically an invalid field would not fire $watch events once that flag is set you have the potential of passing bad values to other directives or functions.

Answer (score 1):

AllowInvalid can be useful in situations where you want to do something with the invalid value. A good example would be to create a password strength display directive. If you do not allow passwords under say 7 characters, you wouldn't know the user is typing until the get to the 8th character thus you won't be able to give feedback.

Using AllowInvalid does not mark the field as valid so you can still use form.password.$invalid to display error messages.

Before submitting you can check if the field or even more generic form is valid before passing the data over.